# How to determine whether a matrix is positive definite or not, when eigenvalues are complex number?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some Jacobian matrix, some of their eigenvalues are complex numbers, so how to determine whether a matrix is positive define or not, when eigenvalues are complex numbers?

Comment: What definition of positive definite are you using?  In the most common definition, only symmetric matrices (which have only real eigenvalues) can be positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the definition of the positive definiteness you are using. If you are using this,

\begin{equation}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow x^TAx \ge 0
\end{equation}

Then there is no condition as such on the nature of eigenvalues (in the sense that real or imaginary). There are matrices which have imaginary eigenvalues but satisfy the above equation. In general positive definiteness is defined for symmetric matrices.

$A = \begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$

This is clearly not going to have real eigenvalues as it rotates the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$ space. (But do note that $Re(eigenvalue)\ge 0$).

To be precise, eigenvalues are $2+i$, $2-i$.

Taking $x^TAx$,

taking $x = (x1, x2)$

\begin{equation}
x^TAx = 2x_1^2 - x_1x_2 + x_1x_2 + 2x_2^2 \ge 0 \ \forall x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

Though this matrix satisfies the condition, it has imaginary eigenvalues.

**Note** if eigenvalue's real component is positive this doesn't mean that matrix is PSD.

#### Another method to approach this is,

Any matrix $A$ can be written as

\begin{equation}
A = \frac{A + A^T}{2} + \frac{A - A^T}{2}
\end{equation}

sum of symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices.

So, $x^TAx$ is

\begin{equation}
x^TAx = x^T\frac{A + A^T}{2}x + x^T\frac{A - A^T}{2}x
\end{equation}

Its well known that

\begin{equation}
x^T\frac{A-A^T}{2}x = \frac{(x^TAx)_{1 \times 1} - (x^TAx)_{1 \times 1}^T}{2} = 0 
\end{equation}

So to check the positive semidefiniteness of a non-symmetric matrix, we can, in fact, check the **positive semidefiniteness of the symmetric component of the matrix.**

In the previous example, the symmetric component is,

$A = \begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix} = 2I$

which is positive semidefinite. So the matrix itself is positive semidefinite.